# Change text color in FPDF for text within cell

Tags: php, pdf, text, colors, fpdf

I want to change the text colour for just the text "HACCP Bulker Check" in the below code:

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width * 2, $cell_height, "HACCP Bulker Check\nPre-loading foreign object free", 'TLR', 1);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
```

Is there a way to do this? The rest of the text needs to be black.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the text?

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width * 2, $cell_height, "HACCP Bulker Check", 'TLR', 1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width * 2, $cell_heigt, "Pre-loading foreign object free", 'LR', 1);
```

You might need to adjust the cell widths. Note the changed border value for the second cell.